# Can t stop the programm

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the code of a spambot that I've made, but I don't know how to change the running boolean for the code to start and stop when I press the button. It also freeze after I type the first letter in the input, but the program still runs in background.

```
from tkinter import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

    keyboard = Controller()

running = True
idx = 0

def start():
    global running
    running = True

def stop():
    global running
    running = False

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()

root.geometry("500x300")
root.title("Spambot")

write = Label(text="Insert sentence then print the button:")
button = Button(text="Spam", command=start)
stop = Button(text="Stop", command=stop)
enter = Entry(root, textvariable = var) 

write.pack()
    enter.pack()
    button.pack()
    stop.pack()

time.sleep(2)

while True:

    if idx % 500 == 0:
        root.update()

    if running:

        for char in var.get():
            keyboard.press(char)
            keyboard.release(char)
            time.sleep(1)
        idx += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You never get to the `root.mainloop()` call, because you're stuck in that `while True:` loop forever. This means you never handle any events—button clicks, updates, or otherwise.

Comment: so, how can i fix it ?

Comment: You need to rewrite your program around the event loop. Instead of a `while True:` that sleeps for a second at a time, you need a function that gets called by the event loop, does some work, and returns quickly (possibly after asking the event loop to call the same function or a different one 1 second later, with the `after` method). This is too hard to explain in detail in Stack Overflow comments; you really need a tutorial on the basics of event loop programming.

Comment: I understand what your trying to explain but my python skills are ow and i can t code that, but thanks

Comment: That's why you need to work through a basic tutorial before anyone can help you code this. Event loops are one of those abstractions that seems like magic until it suddenly clicks in your head after following through a few examples, and then it's a lot easier. Trying to explain it before you've had that "aha" moment is next to impossible, and just giving you working code without explaining it will make it impossible for you to extend and maintain your own code.

Comment: Once you've got the basic idea but are still confused by the details… I've tried to explain that (e.g., [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html), but I'm sure others can do it better than me. But at that point, you can usually ask a specific question, which is a lot easier.

Comment: Do you think it is funny to have your profile pic to be that of one of the worst terrorist in history? I suggest you change your pic.

Comment: Ok, im going to change it